# C++ management of strings allocated by a literal

Tags: c++, string, memory

Do I need to take care of memory allocation, scope and deletion of C++ strings allocated by a literal?

For example:

```cpp
#include <string>

const char* func1() {
    const char* s = "this is a literal string";
    return s;
}

string func2() {
    std::string s = "this is a literal string";
    return s;
}

const char* func3() {
    std::string s = "this is a literal string";
    return s.c_str();
}

void func() {
    const char*  s1 = func1();
    std::string s2 = func2();
    const char*  s3 = func3();

    delete s1; //?
    delete s3; //?
}
```

- `func2`: I don't need to `delete s2`.
- `func3`: Do I need to `delete s3`?

Is `func1` correct? Is character memory content still available after it leaving `func1`'s scope? If yes, should I delete it when I do not need it anymore?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579874/lifetime-of-a-const-string-literal-returned-by-a-function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267114/scope-of-string-literals

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- `func1()` returns a pointer to a string literal. You must not delete string literals.
- `func2()` (presumably, you omitted the `std::` prefix) returns a `std::string`. It takes care of itself.
- `func3()` returns a pointer to a string that's managed by a `std::string` object that's destroyed when the function exits. You must not touch that pointer after the function returns.
- You would have to take care of the memory returned by this function:

  ```
  const char* func4() {
     char* s = new char[100];
     // fill char array with a string
     return s;
  }
  ```

However, manual resource management is tricky. For starters, if a function returns a naked pointer, you don't know whether it points to one objects (`char`) or an array thereof and whether you need to delete it. You should avoid all that and just stick to `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a different problem with s3, namely that the function func3() returns a pointer into an object that goes out of scope when the function returns. Don't.

*To clarify*: Your local string object within func3() will cease to exist on return of the function, so no need to delete. However, you still have a pointer to its internal buffer, which you return. You can't use that.

Very good and detailed past answer here, lest more confusion ensues: [Is it more efficient to return a const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275795/is-it-more-efficient-to-return-a-const-reference/275840)

Comment: @Alexander Rautenberg - Better would be to ask him to use a reference for s3, rather than a pointer. And it is correct anyways.

Comment: The problem remains the same for func3() or s3, if you use a pointer or a reference. There is nothing correct about the way func3() is coded.

Comment: @Alexander Rautenberg - Not in a reference, for strings, if you check properly. Returning an object but binding it to a const object increases its lifetime till the program exits. If he returns a string instead of a char pointer he is fine.

Comment: @DumbCoder If he returns a std::string, he's fine, agreed. But I think the original question was about using delete with pointers in different situations, and this is where func3() cannot be made to fit in.

Answer (score 1):

I snip the relevant code to each function and treatment of its return value, and comment below:

```
const char* func1() {
   const char* s = "this is a literal string";
   return s;
}
const char*  s1 = func1();
delete s1; //?
```

You can't delete `s1`, as the string it points to does not live on the heap.

```
string func2() {
   string s = "this is a literal string";
   return s;
}
string s2 = func2();
```

This is fine. `func2`'s `s` goes out of scope and cleans up. `s2` will duplicate the string from `s`, and also clean itself up at the end of `func`.

```
const char* func3() {
   string s = "this is a literal string";
   return s.c_str();
}
const char*  s3 = func3();
delete s3; //?
```

`func3` returns a pointer to a string that has been freed. You will get a double free exception upon execution of `delete s3`.

Answer (score 1):

In func3 your string local is created by the compiler calling the implicit constructor `string(const char*)` initializing its internal buffer with a copy of the string literal. You then return a pointer to the internal buffer of the string which promptly goes out of scope and gets freed as soon as the function returns.

Comment: To be more precise, the allocated string (temporary) gets destroyed not when the function returns per se, but when the expression which called func3() ends. This is not a subtlety. It is a feature guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: @jose.angel.jimenez Very interesting. Does this guarantee have a name, or do you know a good search term to learn more about its purpose?

Comment: You can check it in the latest draft of the C++11 specification, section "12.2 Temporary objects" paragraph 3: "[...] Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception [...]" http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf