# Deallocate wchar_t* of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, wchar-t, memory-management

I have a vector of wchar_t* like this:

```
std::vector<wchar_t*> myvector;
```

and a function that take a string and insert it into the vector

```
void myfunction(wchar_t* mystring)
{
    myvector.push_back(mystring);
}

myfunction(L"this is my string");
```

when I close the program I need to delete the allocated memory of the vector so that I don't have a memory leak, to do this I'm trying to do this:

```
for (std::vector<wchar_t*>::iterator it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it)
{
    delete [] *it;
}
```

it compiles, all works fine but when it's time to deallocated the memory I have a rountime error:

[error http://k.min.us/iklWGE.png](http://k.min.us/iklWGE.png)

why? how can I fix this?

Comment: You should use `std::wstring` to avoid running into such problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this `myfunction(L"this is my string");` you don't create a new string. It's a constant string that's stored somewhere in your exe. And since you don't explicitly `new` it, you don't need to `delete` it either.
Only use `new and delete` and `new[] and delete[]` in pairs!

Answer (score 1):

Only `delete` what you `new`. You are not using `new` anywhere, neither directly nor indirectly so there’s nothing to delete. As Xeo said, a better solution is to use `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 0):

[You should not delete string literals.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873241/c-string-allocation)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated any memory yourself. If you haven't got any new[]'s in your code you don't need any delete[]'s either.