# What is the terminology for this use of a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, com, bstr

A co-worker wrote the following code, which I am convinced is wrong.

I want to explain the problems to him, but don't know the proper term, so I cannot find references to support my position:

**His code:**

```
BSTR someString = _bstr_t(L"Hello World");
```

**Why I think it is wrong:**
I believe that `_bstr_t(L"Hello World");` calls the constructor for `_bstr_t`, and creates a short-lived temporary variable of that type.  That temporary will be automatically deleted, and its string-space freed up, immediately after this line of code (after the semi-colon sequence point).
This will leave `someString` pointing to memory that has been freed.

**Questions:**
What is the proper term for that call of a constructor?

Can you point to some references/terms/pages that describe the use in detail?

Is there a term for the temporary `_bstr_t` object?
I guess I would call it an "anonymous, temporary variable", but I don't know if that is technically accurate.

(*or maybe I'm completely wrong in my analysis.... if so, I'd love to know*)

---

**For clarification:**

[_bstr_t is a C++ class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx), commonly used by Microsoft to wrap their BSTR type, so it has constructors/destructors/operators, etc.

`BSTR` is a typedef for just a `WCHAR*`, so it does not have any logic.  Its just a dumb-pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in question

```
 BSTR someString = _bstr_t(L"Hello World");
```

is doing a [*conversion constructor* call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905907/57428) which creates a `bstr_t` instance using the passed `wchar_t[]`. This by itself is just fine. For example if you wanted to call a function accepting `BSTR` and pass a string literal in there you could easily do this:

```
someFunction( _bstr_t(L"Hello World") ); // OKAY
```

and this would be okay because the temporary would survive *until the end of the whole statement* which ends where the semicolon resides (this is how C++ temporaries work).

However the code in question is not okay because the `_bstr_t` instance is then used to instantiate a `BSTR` instance (using a conversion operator in class `bstr_t`) which lives longer than the temporary (the temporary is destroyed at the semicolon and the `BSTR` pointer `someString` lives well beyond that). So you get a dangling `BSTR` pointer `someString` using which leads to undefined behavior. It may even look working if the OLE heap chooses to keep the memory used for the string mapped into the process address space.

`class _bstr_t` is supplied with the implementation (file comutil.h in Windows SDK) so you can step into the code with your debugger and see that there's one `SysAllocString()` call when the temporary is created and then one `SysFreeString()` call when it is destroyed and the latter happens before the code proceeds to the next line. Therefore the string object in the OLE heap is deallocated before the code proceeds to the next line and `someString` pointer is dangling immediately after the code in question. I guess this would be enough to convince even the most skeptical person.

So yes, you're right that the code is erroneous. The correct code would be:

```
 _bstr_t someString(L"Hello World");
```

Comment: Thanks, the term *"conversion constructor"* is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You're right.

A `BSTR` is a typedef for `wchar_t *`, and `CComBSTR/_bstr_t` has a non-const conversion operator to `wchar_t *`.

Thus, a temporary `_bstr_t` is allocated, a pointer to its beginning is assigned to `someString` via the conversion operator, and the object is released as it goes out of scope. You then get a dangling pointer.

You can use

```
_bstr_t someString ("Hello World");
```

instead, or even `_bstr_t someString = "Hello, World";`.

Comment: Glad you agree. My issue is with "scope".  I typically consider an object's scope to be bracket-to-bracket; from `{` until the matching `}`.  But there are no brackets here... so what exactly defines the temporary `_bstr_t`'s "scope"?

Comment: @abelenky: I'm no language lawyer -- maybe you can ask this exact question here on SO, people will be glad to answer. What I'm sure about is that the destructor is called after the assignment. Contrast to `const _bstr_t& someString = "Hello, World"`, which calls the copy constructor and whose scope is delimited by brackets.

Comment: @abelenky: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041959/life-scope-of-temporary-variable