# C++ what happens first - destruction of function's parameters or handling of function's return values?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have the following code:

```
class thing {
    public:
        thing(const thing& x) { cout << "copy" << endl; }
        thing() { cout << "create" << endl; }
        ~thing() { cout << "destroy" << endl; }

        thing& operator=(const int& rhs) { cout << "assign" << endl; }
};

int foo(thing x) {
    return 5;
}

int main() {
    thing bar;
    thing newThing;
    newThing = foo(bar);

    getchar();
}
```

When I run this, at the point where my program reaches the `getchar()`, I expect to see the following output:

```
create // since bar is default constructed
create // since newThing is default constructed
copy // since bar gets passed by value into foo
destroy // since foo's local thing `x` is destructed when foo ends
assign // since the 5 returned by foo is assigned to newThing
```

Instead, I get this:

```
create
create
copy
assign
destroy
```

Note that assign and destroy have swapped from what I expected.

What's up with this? Why does the assignment appear to happen *before* the local `x` is destructed? Note that if I declare a local `thing` in the body of foo, it gets destructed before the assignment happens, as I would expect.

Comment: Have you disabled all compiler optimizations? If optimizations are enabled, the results may be altered by reordering and/or inlining.

Comment: Temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression they are a part of, so the temporary is destroyed after the assignment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506793/c-life-span-of-temporary-arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this signature:

```
int foo(thing x) {
    return 5;
}
```

You are creating a function where the instance of `thing` is a parameter. Parameters are passed in by the *caller* of the method, that mean that the expression here:

```
newThing = foo(bar);
```

creates a temporary object of `thing` which is copied from `bar`. Those temporaries have a lifetime upto the end of the full expression, therefore the destructor of this temporary is called *after* the assignment happened.

Why is that so? Because the compiler only generates one function called `foo` and this function can not construct `x` locally - it would not know with which parameters to construct it. There could be multiple constructors which could be valid and several different sets of parameters. The compiler therefore *must* construct the temporary on the caller's side of the call.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are constructed and destructed by the caller, not by the method. 'foo()'s local thing' isn't foo()'s at all, it is the caller's: the caller destroys it.

Comment: Parameters passed by value are owned by and destructed by the called method, not the caller. For stdcall, this is necessary because the callee pops the stack before returning, meaning the parameter would disappear into oblivion before returning (thus the callee _must_ be the one to destruct the object). In cdecl, it could go either way because the caller fixes the stack, but VS at least (not sure about gcc and clang) still destruct the object from inside the method call before returning, perhaps for code bloat considerations.