# LPTSTR to LPWSTR conversion using ATL

Tags: c++, unicode, atl, tchar

Suppose I have this:

```
LPTSTR MyString = _T("A string"); 
void SomeFunction(LPCWSTR param);
```

I can use one of the [ATL conversion macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx#atl70stringconversionclassesmacros), `CT2CW`, and the function works as expected:

```
SomeFunction(CT2CW(MyString));
```

However, if I have something like this:

```
LPWSTR WString = CT2CW(MyString); // or CT2W, it doesn't matter
```

Now `WString` doesn't contain what I would expect it to; it just appears to contain garbage. I am sure this is some funky pointer business, but I am stumped.

Comment: Why do you monkey around with `TCHAR` **at all**? Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant/3002494#3002494 Anyway, in what way does `WString` not contain what you expected? Is such the case in the next line, or only after returning?

Comment: @Deduplicator I am modifying a huge existing code base. I can't do anything about it unless I redo and retest tons of code for no good reason. `WString` contains completely garbled data.

Comment: Well, I wish you luck and perseverence than. There are always those cases...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory used to store the string is freed when the `CT2CW` object is destroyed.

In fact, the MSDN page you linked to already mentions this exact problem.

In `SomeFunction(CT2CW(MyString));`, the temporary `CT2CW` object is not destroyed until the entire statement, including the function call, has executed - see ["Life span of temporary arguments?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506793/c-life-span-of-temporary-arguments).

In `LPWSTR WString = CT2CW(MyString);`, the temporary `CT2CW` object is destroyed when the entire statement has executed. That means that after this statement executes, `WString` points to memory that has been freed.

The solution, as already mentioned in the MSDN article you linked to, is to use a local variable instead of a temporary object:

```
CT2CW WString(MyString);
```

Local variables are not destroyed until the end of their scope.

Comment: Thanks. But now when I try `LPTSTR MyString = _T("A string"); LPWSTR WString; CT2W WString(MyString);`, it gives me this error `"error C2040: 'WString' : 'ATL::CA2W' differs in levels of indirection from 'LPWSTR'"`. I assume *this* is a pointer problem?

Comment: @quantumSoup why are you trying to define `WString` twice with different types? (`CT2W` can be implicitly converted to `LPWSTR` already, if that's what the confusion is from)

Comment: It all makes sense now. I have not coded in C++ since college for assignments, and I am overthinking it. Thanks.