# Lifetime of temporaries inside a function call

Tags: c++, lifetime

Please see the following code examples:

(A)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
struct wrapper {
  int&& x;
};

void f(wrapper a) { std::cout << std::move(a.x) << std::endl; }
int g() { return 0; }

int main() {
  f(wrapper{g()});
}
```

(B)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
struct wrapper {
  int&& x;
};
wrapper make_wrapper(int&& x) {
  return{ std::move(x) };
}

void f(wrapper a) { std::cout << std::move(a.x) << std::endl; }
int g() { return 0; }

int main() {
  f(make_wrapper(g()));
}
```

Are these examples valid? That is, are temporaries created by `g` alive until the execution of `f` finishes? What happens when `f` takes its argument as a reference?

Comment: Is there any particular doubt you have that the general life-time rule for temporaries applies or is sufficient? (i.e. lifetime ends at the end of the full-expression creating the temporary)

Comment: Uhm.. I think I do not fully understand the general rule. I once thought that lifetime for a temporary is ended with the semicolon, but I've once encountered that this kind of argument wrapping led me to a problem. I don't recall what exactly was the problem, though. Maybe I just misunderstood about the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Life span of temporary arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506793/c-life-span-of-temporary-arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both code examples are valid.

The only temporaries created in your code are the `int` returned from `g()`, the `wrapper` returned from `make_wrapper` and the `wrapper` created via aggregate-initialization in `wrapper{...}`.

All of these happen lexically in the full-expression

```
f(wrapper{g()});
```

or

```
f(make_wrapper(g()));
```

and in general temporaries' lifetime ends at the end of the full-expression that they were created in. Therefore all your temporaries live until the end of the respective line throughout the call to `f`, and none of them are used outside their lifetime.

There are only few exceptions to this lifetime rule and all of them extend the lifetime. In fact binding the temporary `int` returned from `g()` to a `int&&` subobject via aggregate-initialization actually extends the lifetime of the temporary to that of the reference.

Therefore

```
wrapper w{g()};
```

would actually not have a dangling reference member, even in following statements.