# In general, what should the return type of the getter for an STL container be?

Tags: c++, getter-setter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should accessors return values or constant references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613823/should-accessors-return-values-or-constant-references)

First of all, let's ignore the setters and getters are/aren't evil. :)

My question is, if I have a class that has some `std::` container as a member, let's say `string`, what should the return type of the getter be? I kind of prefer `const T&` compared to `T` for performance reasons... I know that most of the time users will make a copy anyway, but I guess not all the time.  Am I wrong?

So in general what is better:

```
std::string get_name() const;
```

OR

```
const std::string& get_name() const;
```

Comment: You may not want talk about why setters/getters are evil, but you've hit on one of the main problems with them....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return a constant reference. If the user wants to make a copy, no skin off your back.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the consideration:

1) return a copy `string`. Then the documentation is simple ("returns the current value of...") and the function is slow (I doubt there are many circumstances where a compiler is smart enough to omit the copy, even where the return value is used only within a single expression. It's theoretically possible for the compiler to recognize `string` as a value type with side-effect-free copies, and also to prove that the referand cannot change during the period in which the caller uses the copy, and therefore use a reference instead. But will it do all that?).

2) return a reference `const string&`. Then the documentation is complex, ("returns a reference to a `string` object containing the current value of... This reference remains valid for the following time... It continues to contain the same value for the following subset of that time..."). The function is fast if the caller doesn't need a copy. The implementation of the class is pretty much constrained to always in future store that string as a `string` data member, because it will not otherwise have anything to return with suitable lifetime.

Aliasing is potentially fast (if it avoids copies) but complex (since referands can change or disappear), so functions that return references are potentially fast but complex. Furthermore, (1) is a "getter that returns a property of the object", but (2) is a "getter that returns a private member of the object". So if getters are evil then (2) is *more* evil than (1).

I would generally return the reference if the getter is essentially there as a hack for other tightly-coupled classes to get at the data, or if the class has *very obvious* semantics for when it will change, for example "never during the lifetime of the object", or if the string is expected to be so huge that it's reasonable to expose it by reference simply because taking a copy of it *should* be rare and so callers will be expecting view behavior rather than value behavior. I'd probably return the value if the interface is supposed to be compatible-forever, just to be safe, unless the class I'm writing is explicitly designed as "a thing that holds a big string and does X for you whilst still letting you see the string".

Immutable garbage-collected strings make this problem go away, which is probably one of the reasons they're attractive to designers of higher-level languages.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the most common use of the getter.

If that string is going to be used since the moment of the get operation untill the end of the program, a copy operation might be advised as you dont want to "make a promise" to the user about the life time of the string.

If that string is going to be used momentarly, use a reference.

If your entire system is using some string repository, that ensures that all string's life times are known. You can safely return a reference from that repository.

Answer (score 1):

In general a const reference is ideal. As Kerrek said, if they need a copy they can make it themselves. The only place this can potentially cause issues is entirely on the onus of the receiver of the reference. For example,  when a const reference var is  is *receiving* the result of an object member returning a const reference, and that object is  later destroyed independent of the lifetime of the reference variable, you've effectively "remembered" a pointer (loose term) that is no longer valid; i.e. :

```
const std::string& myref = myobj->getString();
...
delete myobj;
```

But you should have knowledge of this (since you're writing the code) and therefore should plan to avoid it in the first place. *They* should have made a copy rather than taking the reference, it is still best-practice to return the reference regardless.

Comment: what about someone who writes `auto str = myobj->getString();`?

Comment: I'm afraid i can't answer that Chris. I am both ashamed and humbled to admit I haven't studied the C++11 standard and don't use a compliant version of it in my work. Thus the reason you don't see me post answers about it. There are a *ton* of people on here that do know the C++11, some of them downright scary-know. I'm never afraid to admit when I don't know, so maybe someone else does.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: `auto` works like template argument deduction, so no problem there.

Comment: Thanks, Kerrek. I really need to see all the stuff they added in that standard if I ever get some downtime @ work.

Comment: My point is that its very easy for the person writing the code to NOT have knowledge of this and not realize they should be making an extra, explicit copy.

Comment: You mean the 'auto' may deduce to a const-reference var rather than a regular var that introduces a byval copy ? helluva good question.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: But, you don't need to be explicit about the copy.  `auto str = myobj->getString();` will make a copy.

Comment: @WhozCraig: No. `auto str` deduces as `std::string`. You need `auto const & str` to get a const-reference.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley is that part of the standard of auto vars being assigned refs? I truly don't know (look up a couple of comments).

Comment: OK. thanks all three of you. Mucho apprec the knowledge suck.

Comment: @WhozCraig: As Kerrek said, auto follows the same rules as template argument deduction.  If you want to understand template argument deduction, I think no resource exists that exceeds the legendary Stephan T. Lavavej: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-2-of-n

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Oh template deduction I'm firm on. its the extensions to the language in C++11 that I'm not familiar with. I really need to work less and play (read C++ standards) more.

Comment: BTW I made a Q couple of weeks ago, that has this explained: accepted answer is really nice    12052474

Comment: Or another possibility: `const char &c = myobj->getFilename()[0]; myobj->something_that_opens_the_file();`. Now `c` is no longer guaranteed valid in C++03, because (as an implementation detail) opening the file called `c_str` on the string. I agree with you what the problem is, I don't think I agree that the user necessarily has knowledge of changes, at least not without what could be quite a bit of work. Often they will, but it depends on the class.