# C++ getter temporary vs const reference

Tags: c++

I have some class that stores vector. And I have getter for it

```
class Data{
  private:
    std::vector<Point*> points;

  public:
    inline std::vector<Point*> getPoints(){
      return points;
     }

}
```

When I call getPoints() will it return temporary object? Or it will just copy it? 
Or I should return const reference, instead?

**UPDATE**

---

And what if I have another class that hold my Data, which also have a getter:

```
class Controller{
private:
  Data *data;

public:
  inline std::vector<Point*> getPoints(){
     return data->getPoints();
  }
}
```

Should both of them be const reference, if I want them not to be copied?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should accessors return values or constant references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613823/should-accessors-return-values-or-constant-references)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method makes a copy of `points`. Modifications to the vector itself will not be propagated to the `points` inside your class. You could return a `const` reference instead to avoid copying. The caller would be able to copy if he wants, but he would be in control.

Note that the copy that is made when returning a vector is shallow. This means that the individual points are exposed: if the caller makes modifications to points (as opposed to making modifications to the vector) these modifications will propagate to the points pointed to by the vector inside your class.

Protecting the content of `Point`s is a lot harder - it would require you to do manual copying. It would also require your caller to make manual freeing. In general, though, you would be better off using smart pointers ([`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) for easier resource management.

Comment: @tower120 Correct. Had they been values, they would be copied as well.

Comment: please, look my updated question. As I understand, current implementation will copy my "points" twice.

Comment: @tower120 There will be only one copy of the vector - the compiler is smart enough to optimize away the second copy.

Comment: By the way - why NVRO not happens here?

Comment: @tower120 NVRO optimizes away the constructor call of the vector that you called `pa` in your example, proceeding straight to populating  it with the data returned from `getPoints` member function. It does not eliminate copying from `points` to `pa`, but it makes that copy faster.

Answer (score 0):

It will copy your original vector.

Return a const reference if you don't want to have it that way.