# Returning const reference for vectors

Tags: c++

In C++

I have code like:

```cpp
class Blah
{
...
};

typedef vector<Blah*> blahVec;

class Kuku
{
   blahVec _blahVecVar;
   blahVec& getBlahVec() { return _blahVecVar; } 
   blahVec getBlahVec() const { return _blahVecVar; }//Line in Concern
```

Should the Line in Concern be: `const blahVec& getBlahVec() const { return _blahVecVar; }` for returning by reference so that there is no copy of the vector or the previous line:
`blahVec getBlahVec() const { return _blahVecVar; }`
returns by reference?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards.

Comment: No, it returns by value, i.e. potentially copies the vector. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091046/what-should-a-c-getter-return)

Comment: Yes alagner, thanks a lot!