# pybind11 change elements in list in a class from the python side

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Suppose I have a class `Smol`:

```c++
class Smol {
    std::string name;
    int value;

public:
    Smol(std::string name_, int val){
        name = name_;
        value = val;
    }

    void set_name(std::string new_name){
        name = new_name;
    }
    std::string get_name(){
        return name;
    }
};
```

and `Big` that will contain a vector of `Smol`s:

```c++
class Big {
    std::vector<Smol> contents;
    std::string name;
public:
    Big(){};

    void set_contents(std::vector<Smol> contents_){
        contents = contents_;
    }

    std::vector<Smol> get_contents(){
        return contents;
    }

    void add_element(Smol element){
        contents.push_back(element);
    }
};
```

I expose them to python as follows:

```c++
PYBIND11_MODULE(big_smol_test, m){
    m.doc() = "testing one two";

    py::class_<Smol>(m, "Smol")
        .def("get_name", &Smol::get_name)
        .def("set_name", &Smol::set_name)
        .def(py::init<std::string, int>())
        .def_property("name", &Smol::get_name, &Smol::set_name)
        ;

    py::class_<Big>(m, "Big")
        .def("set_contents", &Big::set_contents)
        .def("get_contents", &Big::get_contents)
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_property("contents", &Big::get_contents, &Big::set_contents)
        ;
}
```

I want to be able to edit the names of `Smol`s contained in an instance of `Big`:

```python
from build.big_smol_test import Big, Smol

s1 = Smol("foo", 1)
s2 = Smol("bar", 5)

b = Big()
b.set_contents([s1, s2])

b.contents[0].name = "lorem"
```

But the name remains as `"foo"`. How would I achieve this? Not sure if I want to make `contents` a vector of pointers, as I'd like to be able to change `s1` without affecting `b`, for instance.

Comment: `void set_contents(std::vector<Smol> contents_)` -- You do realize that you should be passing `contents_` by const reference?  Then this: `std::vector<Smol> get_contents()` returns a *copy* of the vector in the `Big` class, not the actual member `contents`.   So is `get_contents` supposed to return the actual vector in `Big`, or a copy of the `vector`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20091148/4165552

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ah, that makes sense. I also want to be able to get a copy of `s1` from `contents`, though. Maybe then I make `Smol` pickleable and use `copy` in python?

Comment: `std::vector<Smol>& get_contents()` -- I do not know pybind, but you should start with this.  This returns the actual vector by reference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So that kind of works: `b.contents[0].name = "lorem"` does change the name, but if I do: `s3 = b.contents[0]` and `s3.name = "new"`,  `b.contents[0]` also changes its name, unsurprisingly. But then this seems to be default python behavior as well (if I write the classes in pure python), so I guess `copy` it is.