# 'this' argument to member function has type 'const', but my function is not actually 'const'

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, vector, stdmap

I have a C++ `std::map` that I'm using to store information about connected components. Here's the segment of code from my `BaseStation` class, it's very basic

```
//Constructor
BaseStation(string name, int x, int y){
    id = name;
    xpos = x;
    ypos = y;
}

//Accessors
string getName(){
    return id;
}
```

In my main code, I have a map declared as

`map<BaseStation, vector<string> > connection_map;`

The `connection_map` is updated in a while loop as follows, and then for my own debugging purposes I want to dump the contents of the map. I append a BaseStation object to the map (as the key) and as the value we have the list of links to the BaseStation object:

```
connection_map[BaseStation(station_name, x, y)] = list_of_links; 
list_of_links.clear();

for(auto ptr = connection_map.begin(); ptr != connection_map.end(); ++ptr){
    cout << ptr->first.getName() << " has the following list: ";
    vector<string> list = ptr->second;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        cout << list[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This is the error I get in my main when I try to compile my code via clang++:

```
server.cpp:66:11: error: 'this' argument to member function 'getName' has type
  'const BaseStation', but function is not marked const
            cout << ptr->first.getName() << " has the following list: ";
```

and in VSCode, the tooltip highlight at the cout (`cout << ptr->first.getName()`) is the following:

```
the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member 
function "BaseStation::getName" -- object type is: const BaseStation
```

I don't understand what's going on, as the `getName()` function is most definitely not constant, and nowhere do I declare my `BaseStation` object as const either. If someone could help me out that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: change to `string getName() const {  return id; }`

Comment: @M.M, it will be better to return `const string&` instead of `string` for better optimisation without relying on compiler.

Comment: @iammilind disagree as that can introduce dangling references. It could perhaps return a `string_view`

Comment: @M.M, `string_view` seems for C++17 or later. I am unable to see any issue in return by const reference. It will be helpful, should you give a code example demonstrating the "dangling reference" issue?

Comment: @iammilind [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134777/1505939)

Comment: @M.M, that's not a real world problem. No sane coder deletes a pointer/reference in the same function. Yes, it's a coding problem, but it can also happen when the pointer is returned.

Comment: @iammilind it is not uncommon to write something like `const string& foo = bar().get_name();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) stores the key as `const`.

> value_type    `std::pair<const Key, T>`

That means when you get the key from `map` (like `ptr->first`), you'll get a `const`  `BaseStation`.

I think you should declare `BaseStation::getName()` as `const` member function, since it's not supposed to perform modification.